# make div height accommodate integral number of text lines?

Tags: css

If I have a long text inside a `div` that wraps into several lines, can I make the `div` not cut a line vertically on vertical overflow? Can I make my `div` have height expressed in number of lines, or some other way to make it fit integral number of lines?

EDIT: My text does not vertically fit into my `div`. But I want the `div` to show just integral number of lines.

here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/A9VAe/1/

Comment: _“Can I make my div have height expressed in number of lines”_ – no, but for a fixed number of visible lines you can try to find the right `height` to use in accordance to `font-size` and `line-height`. (Maybe you want to give the height in a unit relative to font-size, like `em`.)

Comment: Don't specify div height. make it height:auto;